# Android ConnectivityManager requestNetwork fails on Android 13 when device is connected to another Wifi

Tags: android

I want to programmatically connect to an (IOT) Wifi access point and am using the `ConnectivityManager` `requestNetwork` API. When the phone is not connect to another WiFi (e.g. the home wifi) this works fine and the `requestNetwork` callback `onAvailable` is called. However, when the phone is connected to another Wifi this always results in `onUnavailable` being called. The access point is clearly there and can be connected to via the OS Wifi settings.

How am I to make sense if this? Are there any alternative ways to programmatically connecting to a WiFi for Android 13 without sending the user into the OS settings?

This issue only appears on my Android 13 devices. Android 12 and below seem fine. Compile and target SDK is set to 33.

EDIT: I might be running into this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/256082302.

Comment: Does the phone have location services enabled and does your app have the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission? I am facing the same issue and suspect this may be the problem.